# Visual Studio hangs on debug in my mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a mvc.asp project that integrates with a sockets.io API.

I have a action in my main controller which makes a request to the external API and gets back a JSON formatted data (this part works fine).

Everything works fine when I let visual studio run from start to finish, but when I try to debug the stages **AFTER** getting the data, visual stdio just hangs for minutes (might even be completely stuck), if I click the pause button it will show that it's about to call a function or do a very basic string manipulation but it doesn't, instead it just hangs.

I've added some of my code (tho I'm not sure it's even relevant).

```
    private ActionParams GetAction(int tabID, int startIndex, HashSet<string> existsUsers)
    {
        ActionParams aParams = new ActionParams();
        string data = VmtDevAPI.GetActionHistory(tabID, startIndex); //api call which returns json
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data); //desiralize

        // **things start getting crazy from this point on** it can get stuck on any of the next lines
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            if (item.eventData != null
                && item.eventName != null
                && item.userName != null
                && item.timeStamp != null
                && item.id != null
                && item.eventData.xml != null
                )
            {
                string url = item.eventData.xml;
                XmlObject xml = new XmlObject(url);

                string timeStamp = item.timeStamp.Value.ToString().Trim();
                ...
         }
     }
```

I would REALLY appreciate if anyone has a suggestion to what should I check. I did check many options before writing these lines, however nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with your results being a list of dynamic objects? Try creating a class to map your json results to.